# AEM search core component

Tags: search, aem, aem-6, aem-core-wcm-components

I am doing a POC on AEM search core component, In that if I search something in that search component for the first time its showing the results correctly, while I am searching for second time its shows the same results. I am not changed any code in the core component, can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I am using this comp while search in this component for the first time its showing the results correctly ,but the next time while searching its showing the same results.